# Using workbook_sheetchange event to make numerical values negative within a range of rows

Tags: excel, vba, events

I am creating a budget in excel and I have copy and pasted a whole year worth of monthly budget outlines. Certain expenditures are all on the same row in multiple sheets in this workbook. I want to make it so whenever a numerical value is entered into a cell in those rows, it is immediately changed to a negative value.

There are non-number text in those rows so I want vba to only look for cells in those rows that have numbers.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Rows("22:52")) Is Nothing Then 'VBA change event for all sheets
Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Rows("22:52"))
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Rows("22:52")) Then
            If rng.Value > 0 Then c.Value = 0 - c.Values
                End If
            End If
        Next rng
End Sub
```

The error I get is end if without block if.

Comment: Remove the innermost `End If`. Also `c.Values` looks like two typos: `.Value`, and what is `c`?

Comment: The second instance of `Rows("22:52")` should be `rng.Value`.

Comment: `If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Rows("22:52")) Is Nothing Then` or the activesheet will be used.  Also for the other 2 instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make it so whenever a numerical value is entered into a cell in those rows, it is immediately changed to a negative value.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim aCell As Range
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Rows("22:52")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each aCell In Target
            If aCell.Value2 > 0 Then aCell.Value = -1 * aCell.Value2
        Next aCell
    End If
    
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**Note**: If you plan to change value of sheets which are not active then you will have to do what Tim mentioned on the comment above. For example if `Sheet1` is active and you want to write to `Sheet2`.

Change

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Rows("22:52")) Is Nothing Then
```

to

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Rows("22:52")) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to do!